# openssl utility with subprocess

Tags: python, openssl, subprocess

I am trying to decrypt an encrypted string with password using subprocess and openssl. This is how this works in bash:

```
echo <my_secret> | openssl enc -d -pbkdf2 -base64 -aes-128-ctr -nopad -nosalt -k <my_decr_key>
```

When I run the following code via python I get None in return. Any idea what would be the right way to implement this?

```
import subprocess
secret = "my_secret"
decr = "my_decr_key"
i = subprocess.Popen["echo", secret], stdout=subprocess.PIPE
x = subprocess.run([ "openssl", "enc", "-d", "-pbkdf2", "-base64", "-aes-128-ctr", "-nopad", "-nosalt", "-k", decr], stdin=i.stdout, shell=True) 

print(x.stdout)
None
```

Comment: It's pointless to use `Popen` for echo.  Just write your string to the stdin of the second subprocess.